# Get component content in joomla

Tags: plugins, joomla, components

I'm making a system plugin and I need a way to put html before any components and after header,menu ecc. in other words I need to put html before this in template:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I found what I need:

```
  // get the document object.
  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

  // get the buffer
  $buffer = $doc->getBuffer('component');

  // your string to insert
  $insert_string = "<p>I've been inserted</p>";

  // insert the string
  $buffer = $insert_string . $buffer;

  // reset the buffer
  $doc->setBuffer($buffer, 'component');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the contents of the webpage then you should be making a "content" plugin as opposed to a "system" plugin.

A good place to start is by looking at the `emailcloak` plugin that ships with Joomla! 1.6+ (note that the plugin interface is quite different for Joomla! 1.5 versus the current 1.6/7/2.5 era plugins). If you're working with 1.5 then have a look the `example` plugin that ships with it.

This doc covers "[Creating a content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin)"

Comment: My understanding was that content plugins only had the scope of com_content and system plugins were needed for components (v3.1) is this not the case?

Comment: No, for example `emailcloak` works in modules, weblinks etc — plug-ins are responding to events. Content plugins get `onContentPrepare` and the first param is the `context` which is the component's identifier e.g. you notice that core plugin's check that the context isn't `com_finder.indexer`
Having said that components have to be written correctly to trigger the relevant events for your plugin to work with them.