# How to display content at component position in joomla?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I have developed one search module which searches users in joomla. My problem is it displays content in same module, rather I want it to display at component position. I am not using any other component in that page. My Joomla version is 2.5
Any suggestions???

Comment: hey, You want search result in normal page?  Are you using default module search ?

Answer (score 2):

Under Joomla!'s MVC a module's output is rendered only into the module position, to have content rendered in the main component position you will have to create a matching component that responds to the modules search request.

Comment: Thanks cppl.. I found my solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145248/get-component-content-in-joomla

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to develop it as a component instead of a module. It could probably easily be acheived using the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/)

Comment: Thanks Soren.. I found my solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145248/get-component-content-in-joomla